# How to apply a background to Unordered List using :nth-child?

Tags: html, list, css, css-selectors

I am creating an UL and trying to apply a background-color to every other row using **:nth-child(2n+1)** Each row is basically a sub-item to the main UL, yet I have been able to apply a style to each UL (perhaps the sub-items within the nested UL are interfering).     I've tried almost every combination imaginable,  what am I missing? 
Noy Hadar

```
<style>
#data {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
#data li ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFC;
}
#data li ul:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #3F6;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#data li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    line-height: 24px;
}
</style>


<ul id="data">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Closed Date</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>DOM</li>
                <li>Address</li>
                <li>Price Change</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Closed Date</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>DOM</li>
                <li>Address</li>
                <li>Price Change</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Closed Date</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>DOM</li>
                <li>Address</li>
                <li>Price Change</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Closed Date</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>DOM</li>
                <li>Address</li>
                <li>Price Change</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Closed Date</li>
                <li>Price</li>
                <li>DOM</li>
                <li>Address</li>
                <li>Price Change</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/CPTU4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r476D/ just change it to `#data li ul li:nth-child(2n+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5jda/) fixing it. I'll explain.

```
#data li ul:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #3F6;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What this is doing is selecting the `ul` element that is the nth-child of the `li`, your structure only has one `ul` after the `li` so it's the only one being selected, which is why your entire table is green.

here's what i changed it to:

```
#data li:nth-child(2n+1) ul {
    background: #3F6;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

now we're selecting the `li` (that contains the `ul`) that is the nth-child of the `#data` container, and then we're styling the `ul` that is in that `li`, so we're selecting every other row and then styling it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So awesome!!  That works.   Gosh, there are so many variations to learn!  Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `li` elements not the `ul` so:

```
#data li ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #3F6;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but that wouldn't work, as it it would apply to every other LI.  I need it to apply to every other ROW.

Comment: just `#data li:nth-child(2n+1)` then?

Comment: Nope, because that wouldn't isolate just the top-level LI and include and sub-level LI as well.

Comment: Yea saw the fiddle. Zachs answer should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table.stripedTable {
background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
    .stripedTable tr:nth-child(2n) {
        background-color: #EEE;
        color: #222;
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="stripedTable">
        <tr id="Row 1">     
                    <td>Row 1</td>
            <td id="Cell 1">Hi
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row 2">
                <td>Row 2</td>
                <td id="Cell 2">Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row 3">
                <td>Row 3</td>
                <td id="Cell 3">Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row 4">
                <td>Row 4</td>
                <td id="Cell 4">Cell 4</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```